# Error when trying to access a question

Tags: support, status-norepro

I get the following error whenever I try to access a [specific question](https://superuser.com/questions/507111/if-usb-is-not-listed-in-bios-as-a-boot-option-does-that-mean-the-machine-cant):

[image]

**EDIT:** I can access the question again normally now. Was there a temporary hiccup on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, there was a hiccup on the server.

Comment: Super User works fine, but Android Enthusiasts is down...